# Taking long time to execute Python code for the definition

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the problem definition:

> Given a string of lowercase letters, determine the index of the
>   character whose removal will make a palindrome. If is already a
>   palindrome or no such character exists, then print -1. There will always
>   be a valid solution, and any correct answer is acceptable. For
>   example, if "bcbc", we can either remove 'b' at index or 'c' at index.

I tried this code:

```
# !/bin/python

import sys

def palindromeIndex(s):
    # Complete this function
    length = len(s)
    index = 0
    while index != length:
        string = list(s)
        del string[index]
        if string == list(reversed(string)):
            return index
        index += 1

    return -1

q = int(raw_input().strip())
for a0 in xrange(q):
    s = raw_input().strip()
    result = palindromeIndex(s)
    print(result)
```

This code works for the smaller values. But taken hell lot of time for the larger inputs.
Here is the sample: [Link to sample](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/1854/input14.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1510401524&Signature=4GdBsQ9sUMusS5%2FPnKSA8MQemE0%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

the above one is the bigger sample which is to be decoded. But at the solution must run for the following input:

```
Input (stdin)

3
aaab
baa
aaa

Expected Output

3
0
-1
```

How to optimize the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to convert the `string` to a `list`, as you can compare `strings`. This will remove a computation that is called a lot thus speeding up the process. To reverse a `string`, all you need to do is used `slicing`:

```
>>> s = "abcdef"
>>> s[::-1]
'fedcba'
```

So using this, you can re-write your `function` to:

```
def palindromeIndex(s):
    if s == s[::-1]:
        return -1
    for i in range(len(s)):
        c = s[:i] + s[i+1:]
        if c == c[::-1]:
            return i
    return -1
```

and the tests from your question:

```
>>> palindromeIndex("aaab")
3
>>> palindromeIndex("baa")
0
>>> palindromeIndex("aaa")
-1
```

and for the first one in the [link](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/1854/input14.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1510401524&Signature=4GdBsQ9sUMusS5%2FPnKSA8MQemE0%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) that you gave, the result was:

```
16722
```

which computed in about `900ms` compared to your original `function` which took `17000ms` but still gave the same result. So it is clear that this `function` is a drastic improvement. **:)**

Comment: but will it be faster? As I have given the example it is taking hell lot of time.

Comment: your logic is give very bad output to me. Try with something small then go for big.

Comment: Input (stdin)

3
aaab
baa
aaa

Your Output (stdout)

-1
0
0

Expected Output

3
0
-1

Comment: This is not an answer for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: No I don't think so. If you have confusion ask me what you didn't got. Otherwise my question is clear.

Comment: Well I don't see where this `function` doesn't work... Can you please give a specific input and output which it fails on

Comment: you can test the example as mentioned in the question. The small sample. You will understand where you function fails. It is not given right index numbers fo rthe smaller one then how I can expect it to work on the bigger values.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your `input` and `outputs` mean in the question.. there seems to be `4` inputs and `3` vaguely relating outputs... I thought the idea was that you input `1` `string` and you get back the `index` of the `character` that is needed to be removed in order to make it a palindrome

Comment: The first number if the count the times the loop will accept input. Please check my code. It is working but is not optimized as it is taking hell lot of time.

Comment: @JafferWilson Ahh, I see what you mean now! I'll take a look

Comment: @JafferWilson I have updated the `function`, the reason there was confusion, was that I was testing with your large `string` from the link, where the character that needed to be removed was near the middle. Your examples needed the very first and last character to work properly, and I hadn't tested this part. Essentially, there was an out-by-one error!

Comment: Thats's what I was looking for ... Thanks

Comment: @JafferWilson Your welcome! I know your experienced and already know how the site works, but please drop the `up-vote` as well if you find it useful thank you **:)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that is optimized for the *very* task

```
def palindrome_index(s):
    # Complete this function
    rev = s[::-1]
    if rev == s:
        return -1

    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(s, rev)):
        if a != b:
            candidate = s[:i] + s[i + 1:]
            if candidate == candidate[::-1]:
                return i
            else:
                return len(s) - i - 1
```

First we calculate the reverse of the string. If `rev` equals the original, it was a palindrome to begin with. Then we iterate the characters at the both ends, keeping tab on the index as well:

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(s, rev)):
```

`a` will hold the current character from the beginning of the string and `b` from the end. `i` will hold the index from the beginning of the string. If at any point `a` != `b` then it means that *either* `a` or `b` must be removed. Since there is always a solution, and it is always one character, we test if the removal of `a` results in a palindrome. If it does, we return the index of `a`, which is `i`. If it doesn't, then by necessity, the removal of `b` must result in a palindrome, therefore we return its index, counting from the end.